# No-Data in clipping .vrt file with GDAL

Tags: python, raster, gdal, shapefile

I am facing some problems while clipping the raster file with the polygon shapefile.

I have 8 GeoTIFFs with *different projections* (different UTM Zones). My aim is to clip these rasters to the extent of a shapefile, which consists of multiple polygons. I don't know which GeoTIFF coincide with the polygon.

So the process I am following is,

- Step 1: Making .vrt files for each GeoTIFF file with the target srs
  as EPSG:3857.

  ```
  gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -tap -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r average -tr 9.554628535646874 9.554628535646874 $in_tif $out_vrt -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co BIGTIFF=YES -overwrite
  ```
- Step 2: Making a single .vrt file out of all the .vrt files created
  in step 1.

  ```
  gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list $vrt_list merged_vrt_3857.vrt
  ```

  Here, the `vrt_list` is a text file that has the absolute paths of
  all the .vrt files created in step 1.
- Step 3: Clipping the .vrt file created in step 2 with the shapefile
  where the polygon id is 3.

  ```
  gdalwarp --config GDALWARP_IGNORE_BAD_CUTLINE YES -dstnodata -9999 -tap -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r average -tr 9.554628535646874 9.554628535646874 -cutline $shp_file -cwhere id="3" -crop_to_cutline -co 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE' -co 'BIGTIFF=YES' -overwrite merged_vrt_3857.vrt $out_tif_path
  ```

**The output after clipping in step 3 is coming as no-data only.** The extent, spatial resolution, and CRS are all correct.

My assumption is that we can create a .vrt file out of .vrt files and we can clip the .vrt file directly.

I am using Python version 3.9.5 and GDAL version 3.2.0.

Note: I have tried using `gdalbuildvrt` instead of `gdalwarp` in step 1 too. But got the same errored output.